# Why is bubble sort running faster than selection sort?

Tags: c#, sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I am working on a project that compares the time bubble and selection sort take. I made two separate programs and combined them into one and now bubble sort is running much faster than selection sort. I checked to make sure that the code wasn't just giving me 0s because of some conversion error and was running as intended. I am using `System.Diagnostics;` to measure the time. I also checked that the machine was not the problem, I ran it on Replit and got similar results.

```
{
    class Program
    {
       public static int s1 = 0;
       public static int s2 = 0;
        static decimal bubblesort(int[] arr1)
        {
            int n = arr1.Length;
            var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (arr1[j] > arr1[j + 1])
                    {
                        int tmp = arr1[j];
                        // swap tmp and arr[i] int tmp = arr[j];
                        arr1[j] = arr1[j + 1];
                        arr1[j + 1] = tmp;
                        s1++;
                    }
                }
            }
            sw1.Stop();
            // Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return a;
        }

        static decimal selectionsort(int[] arr2)
        {
            int n = arr2.Length;
            var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
           // for (int e = 0; e < 1000; e++)
           // {

                for (int x = 0; x < arr2.Length - 1; x++)
                {
                    int minPos = x;
                    for (int y = x + 1; y < arr2.Length; y++)
                    {
                        if (arr2[y] < arr2[minPos])
                            minPos = y;
                    }
                    if (x != minPos && minPos < arr2.Length)
                    {
                        int temp = arr2[minPos];
                        arr2[minPos] = arr2[x];
                        arr2[x] = temp;
                        s2++;
                    }
                }

          //  }
            sw1.Stop();
           // Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return a;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of n");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Random rnd = new System.Random();
            decimal bs = 0M;
            decimal ss = 0M;
            int s = 0;
            int[] arr1 = new int[n];
            int tx = 1000; //tx is a variable that I can use to adjust sample size
            decimal tm = Convert.ToDecimal(tx);

            for (int i = 0; i < tx; i++)
            {

                for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
                {
                    arr1[a] = rnd.Next(0, 1000000);
                }

                

                ss += selectionsort(arr1);
                bs += bubblesort(arr1);
            }

            bs = bs / tm;
            ss = ss / tm;

            Console.WriteLine("Bubble Sort took " + bs + " miliseconds");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection Sort took " + ss + " miliseconds");


        }
    }
}
```

What is going on? What is causing bubble sort to be fast or what is slowing down Selection sort? How can I fix this?

I found that the problem was that the Selection Sort was looping 1000 times per method run in addition to the 1000 runs for sample size, causing the method to perform significantly worse than bubble sort. Thank you guys for help and thank you TheGeneral for showing me the benchmarking tools. Also, the array that was given as a parameter was a copy instead of a reference, as running through the loop manually showed me that the bubble sort was doing it's job and not sorting an already sorted array.

Comment: Measuring performance is almost an art.  You need more than one run each and you need to mixup the order they run so one doesnt 'warm up' the other.  Also be sure it is not a debug build. Also be sure to use *identical* data sets.  There are many, many such posts here explaining more

Comment: Bubblesort runs on already sorted array, so it does not have to sort anything. Try deep-copying the input array before execution and run functions on separate instances.

Comment: By the way, besides sorting an already sorted array, your bubble sort is incorrectly implemented - it is not adaptive. Properly implemented bubble sort will not re-sort an already sorted array, *nor will it check past the first full loop if no swaps occurred* - yours still performs O(n^2) checks, even though no swaps are happening. A correctly impelemented bubble sort will generally beat selection sort. Check out this useful website: https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms

Answer (score 5):

To solve your initial problem you just need to copy your arrays, you can do this easily with [ToArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=net-5.0):

> Creates an array from a IEnumerable.

```
ss += selectionsort(arr1.ToArray());
bs += bubblesort(arr1.ToArray());
```

However let's learn how to do a more reliable benchmark with *BenchmarkDotNet*:

- [BenchmarkDotNet Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet/)
- [Official Documentation](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html)

**Given**

```
public class Sort
{
   public static void BubbleSort(int[] arr1)
   {
      int n = arr1.Length;
      for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
         {
            if (arr1[j] > arr1[j + 1])
            {
               int tmp = arr1[j];
               // swap tmp and arr[i] int tmp = arr[j];
               arr1[j] = arr1[j + 1];
               arr1[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public static void SelectionSort(int[] arr2)
   {
      int n = arr2.Length;
      for (int x = 0; x < arr2.Length - 1; x++)
      {
         int minPos = x;
         for (int y = x + 1; y < arr2.Length; y++)
         {
            if (arr2[y] < arr2[minPos])
               minPos = y;
         }

         if (x != minPos && minPos < arr2.Length)
         {
            int temp = arr2[minPos];
            arr2[minPos] = arr2[x];
            arr2[x] = temp;
         }
      }

   }
}
```

**Benchmark code**

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net50)]
[MemoryDiagnoser()]
public class SortBenchmark
{

   private int[] data;

   [Params(100, 1000)]
   public int N;

   [GlobalSetup]
   public void Setup()
   {
      var r = new Random(42);

      data = Enumerable
         .Repeat(0, N)
         .Select(i => r.Next(0, N))
         .ToArray();
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void Bubble() => Sort.BubbleSort(data.ToArray());

   [Benchmark]
   public void Selection() => Sort.SelectionSort(data.ToArray());
}
```

**Usage**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   BenchmarkRunner.Run<SortBenchmark>();
}
```

**Results**

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bubble | 100 | 8.553 us | 0.0753 us | 0.0704 us |
| Selection | 100 | 4.757 us | 0.0247 us | 0.0231 us |
| Bubble | 1000 | 657.760 us | 7.2581 us | 6.7893 us |
| Selection | 1000 | 300.395 us | 2.3302 us | 2.1796 us |

**Summary**

What have we learnt? Your bubble sort code is slower `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Best answer I think. Very useful scenario, considering developers usually don't know how all those aspects like GC/memory/JIT and process warmup affects performance and try to write their own benchmark tools.

Comment: Just to be clear, these N's are very small, so it is hardly a fair comparison. Note that at N=100, there is ~1000x speedup with bubble sort. At N=1000, there is only a ~250x. I'm curious what it would be at N=10e5 or 10e6.

Comment: @NateDiamond arg, the selection sort had  a 1000 iteration for loop in it from the original OP code  :/ ill update

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're passing in the sorted array into Bubble Sort. Because arrays are passed by reference, the sort that you're doing on the array is editing the same contents of the array that will be eventually passed into bubble sort.

Make a second array and pass the second array into bubble sort.